# Conditional Pop message based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling mighty heavily with a code. I'm attempting to have a message box pop up based on different cell value conditions. The code worked at some point and now I can't get it going again. I greatly appreciate any tips or help.  Below is a sample of the code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Business Interruption")

If ws.Range("A1").Value < 0 Then
   MsgBox Prompt:="Error! Try again." 

ElseIf ws.Range("A1") < ws.Range("$B$2") Then
   MsgBox Prompt:="Almost there! Keep trying."
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Simply tellyinig us [It's not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is no good starting point to get help. Reading [ask] and [repro] should help you to enhance your question.

Comment: Clear. Throws of desperation. I self-corrected the issue. I appreciate the example.